# What is logic/algorithm behind a GROUP BY in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

A simple example using a GROUP BY in SQL. I wanted to know the logic behind the GROUP BY clause or code/algorithm for GROUP BY clause.

Select dept_id, count(emp_id)
from employees
group by dept_id

Comment: GROUP BY is used in a Aggregate function i.e. whenever you need to sum or count the results of the query. In your case, since the result is grouped by the dept_id all rows with the same dept_id will be 'grouped' together into the same result row. see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp for examples

Comment: If you want to see what sql is doing (and you are running from SSMS) select include execution plan from the query tab and then run your query.